# Mysql Query to create serial number in the result and where condition apply for that serial number

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause, row-number

I need a query which results a serial number and also a where condition to filter that serial number like "where serial_number between 0 to 10"

```
Select  @rown:=@rown+1 serial_number, user_name as un from user
                            (select @rown := 0) as t
                            where                 
                             (@rown := (@rown + 1)) between 0 and 10
                            ORDER BY u.id_user asc
```

but i didnt get the result in between,
kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `subquery` to implement this:

Try this:

```
SELECT serial_number, un 
FROM (SELECT (@rown:=@rown+1) AS serial_number, user_name AS un 
      FROM USER, (SELECT @rown := 0) AS t 
      ORDER BY u.id_user ASC
    ) AS A
WHERE serial_number BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

Comment: But it take a long time to fetch and display. to rows to fetch is 6 sec,the same time is taken for this query too.

Comment: @Saharsh what if my query have inner join just before where you have written atrown:=0, how it will work in that condition, for example  http://pastebin.com/ZTcm0d39